# Mount to /dev/sdb1 without password

Tags: 12.04, usb, mount

I am unable to mount a USB drive (or SD card) to my system without root access. When I plug in a USB drive, it is visible in the left column of Nautilus, but when I click on it to open it, I receive the error message

**Unable to mount 2.1 GB Filesystem**
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mount: only root can mount /dev/sdb1 on /media/sdb1

I am able to mount the drive using `sudo mount -w /dev/sdb1`, but this causes problems for operations such as creating startup discs, which requires unmounting and remounting the drive.

I suspect this problem may be caused by the fact that when I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04, I had an SD card plugged in. This caused the system to stall during later startups, as it could not find this drive. I remedied this by editing a line of `/etc/fstab` to read

```
/dev/sdb1         /media/sdb1  vfat  noauto          0  0
```

However, I am dual booting Ubuntu with Windows XP, and I have no problem mounting the C: drive of the Windows system without root access, so I feel that this is a problem related to the mount point rather than mounting in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines in /etc/fstab are for persistent disks that are meant to be mounted on every or nearly every boot.  Removable media are handled by a separate system, and don't need to have lines in /etc/fstab.

Remove that line from /etc/fstab and your error will go away.